# How can I make a sidebar menu expand when it is hovered?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what some thing I want to create but I am not able to find the solution please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4d4T.png)

Comment: you can try typing code and seeing what works and what doesn't instead of asking us to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the below html and css code snippet for sidebar menu .

```css
.sidebar-container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .content-container {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .sidebar-logo {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
  
  .sidebar-navigation {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .sidebar-navigation li {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  
  .sidebar-navigation li a {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .sidebar-navigation li .fa {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  .sidebar-navigation li a:active,
  .sidebar-navigation li a:hover,
  .sidebar-navigation li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
  }
  
  .sidebar-navigation li::before {
    background-color: #2574A9;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
    width: 3px;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  .sidebar-navigation li:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .sidebar-navigation .header {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #151515;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
  }
  
  .sidebar-navigation .header::before {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .content-container {
    padding-left: 220px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <h3 style="color: blanchedalmond;" class="sidebar-logo">Heading</h3>
    <ul class="sidebar-navigation">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li>
        <a href="Addproduct" data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Gallery
        </a>
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li>
        <a href="productview" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i> Products
        </a>
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li>
        <a href="vieworder" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i> Orders
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```